# How to split data using regex with Zapier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zapier, webflow

I'm setting up integration between a webflow store and shippo to assist with creating labels and managing shipping. Webflow passes the data as one huge object for address information, however to create a new order in shippo, I need the information parsed, separated as individual line items. I have attempted to use formatter which allows one to extract text, split text, use regex to match data and more.

```
import re
details = re.search(r'(?<=city:\s).*$', input_data[All Addresses])
```

Regex in Python is my best option, yet the result will not find and/or display the data.

Please any experts in Zapier integrations, I need assistance in figuring out a way to parse the incoming data from webflow, pass it to the 'create a order' action with shippo.

Structure of Data:
addressee: string
city: string
country: string
more....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
Combine all the data in one whole string

```
import re
details = re.finall(r'(?<=city:\s).*$', all_addresses)
return details
```

It will you give the list of all matches in the text.

Comment: The output is still matched false. The logic is exactly what I had in mind, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is the exact code I am inputing.  

import re
details = re.findall(r'(?<=city:\s).*$', all_addresses)
return details.match()

Comment: Please help! I can't solve this and it's killing my site shipping integration.

Comment: @techdeus details will be a list of all matches. It doesn't have the method "match()". You can return this list directly or join all the strings.